# Revering doubly Linked List iteratively

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a Doubly linked list which I have to reverse iteratively.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class DLL {

public static Node reverse (Node head){
     if(head == null)
            return null;
        else{
            Node temp=head;
            Node buffer=null;
            while(temp.next != null){            
                buffer=temp.next;
                temp.next=temp.prev;
                temp.prev=buffer;
                temp=buffer;
            }
            head=temp.prev;
            return head;
        }       

}

public static Node insert(Node head,int data){
    if(head == null)
        return new Node(data);
    else{
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp.next != null){
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        Node cur = new Node(data);
        temp.next=cur;
        cur.prev=temp;
        return head;
    }

}

public static void Display(Node head){
    if(head != null){
        System.out.println(head.data);
        Display(head.next);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    Node head= null;
    int size = s.nextInt();

    while(size-- != 0){
        head=insert(head,s.nextInt());
    }

    Display(head);
    head=reverse(head);
    System
    Display(head);
}
```

}

Now i'am getting a reversed list but i'am not able to print first element i.e (last element of original list)
My node class of DLL is like this

```
    class Node {
 int data;
 Node next;
 Node prev;
```

}

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are there sentinel nodes?

Comment: No it just have null as terminator.

Comment: You should add more code, such as the error and the line of code that executes that error.

Comment: The method seems fine to me, maybe the error lies elsewhere, can you post the code where the null pointer exception happens?

Comment: yes i have put my complete code with some edited stuff.